# Compare two Rows in a worksheet and test for Unique values for each and Output in an Column

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I have a worksheet with two columns with different Values, Patient ID (ID#) and Institute.

I want to find the Unique values between the two columns and output as 1 (is unique) and 0 (not unique) in an different column corresponding to each cell.

I need to use an Array as I have 10,000 records to test in each column.

Test Conditions:

Case 1 : PatientID in value (A1 = "HC1") goes to Institute value (B2 = "HG"). This is an unique value, as PatientID and Institute only appear once. Hence Output in value (C1 = "1").

Case 2 : PatientID value (A2 = "HC1") goes to Institute value (B2 = "HG"). This is an not unique; as the same patient goes to the same institute again. Hence Output in value (C2 = "0").

Case 3 : PatientID value (A3 = "HC1") goes to Institute value (B3 = "RH"). This is unique; as the same patient goes to an different Institute. Hence Output in value (C3 = "1").

Case 4 : PatientID value (A4 = "HC2") goes to institute value (B4 = "RH"). This is unique; as  different patient goes to an different institute. Hence the value of Output should be value (C4 = "1").

I need the VB code to do the same.

Currently i use this Excel 2010 Formulae,

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C1442=C3)*($A$2:$A1442=A3))>1,0,1)

where,
Column C is Institute and Column A is PatientID.

This takes insane amount of time to compute. Please HELP.

Thank you

Comment: Isn't case 3 & 4 the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper column to combine the two cells together, then count if those cells are unique.

[image: Combine cells]

Results

[image: Result]

if you want you can hide column C

[image: Hide Column]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use macro for the same, you can do it as follow:

```
Sub TEST()
Set ExcelAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ActiveRange = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
RowCont = ActiveRange.Rows.Count
Dim dataArr() As Variant
ReDim dataArr(RowCont, 1)
For i = 0 To RowCont - 1
InputText = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
If CheckUnique(dataArr, InputText) = True Then
Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = 0
Else
Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = 1
dataArr(i, 0) = InputText
dataArr(i, 1) = i + 1 'store row number
End If
Next
End Sub

Function CheckUnique(dataArr, InputText)
Dim lb As Long, ub As Long, i As Long, result As Boolean
lb = LBound(dataArr)
ub = UBound(dataArr)
result = False
For i = lb To ub
If dataArr(i, 0) = InputText Then
result = True
Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = 0
Exit For
End If
Next i
CheckUnique = result
End Function
```

Output will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. But the output has an error, C1 = 0 and C2=0, when it finds a match, it puts both the field as 0 instead of puting one field as 1 and the other match 0.

Comment: Yeah! I wrote the code like this: if it's unique throughout whole column, it will assign one, otherwise zero. Because what I understood from your post that you want to check unique value.